# nodejs service sends back json. How to populate it in an ejs/html

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

My nodejs application is using express and following post method.

```
app.post("/orderdeliver",function(req,res){
var cellNumber=req.body.mobilenumber;
User.findOne({mobilenumber:req.body.user.mobilenumber}).populate("clothes").exec(function(err,foundUser){
    if(err || foundUser.length<=0){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        //res.render("orderhistory",{user: foundUser})
        res.send(foundUser);
    }
});
```

});

Here i want to send back the results in json format. Which is done by res.send() to the ejs page from which called. Now i want to populate the same page with found results in the json. It is essential that i return the json format only. How to modify the ejs page so that the returned json will get populated in it and old html elements will remain in place. I know res.render() can be used, but that will defeat the purpose of sending back the json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever using EJS keep in mind this two things:

```
- <%= someVariable %>
- <% someCode %>
```

Solution:

Replace `res.send(foundUser)` by `res.render(page,foundUser)`, this way you'll have page as the ejs to be rendered and foundUser as the parameters for your view.

Also your function is wrong you should use this:

```
if(error) {
   return res.render(errorPage,{ error: error.message || error, data: false })
} else {
   return res.render(page,{ error: false, data: foundUser })
}
```

Example using value on the EJS file:

```
<% if(foundUser.name) { %>
<h1><%= foundUser.name %></h1>
<% } %>
```

Comment: I don't want to use res.render() because my node js post method is lie a microservice. It sends back json which can be used by calling page. Usng res.render() will make the html page structure static. I want the html page structure to be defined by the microservice user.

Comment: Ok, then you need to handle it using JS client-side libraries/framework such Angular, then you request the JSON data which is sent using res.send(yourData) and handled by the controller/library from the client side.

Comment: can i handle it in an ejs file?

Comment: If you are using EJS is usually related to use res.render but any case you could use it in EJS using res.send plus third party libraries for client-side

Comment: I am not able to find how to accomplish it using third party library and ejs. If you can elaborate it then i can start from there.

Comment: You could execute a request using jQuery and adding the received value to your HTML elements https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/, it's only an example, but definetively you must to read about client-side vs server-side technologies

Comment: Went through the jquery.post method. That is what i am looking for. Any other simple libraries you can suggest, which can accomplish the same.